# Perl: A script that groups files into a single file

Tags: perl

I have many logs, that are stored daily, under the following names in my var/log directory:

log20130601
log20130602
log20130603
...

Each log has many lines. For example, if I open log20130529 I find:

```
    2013-05-29T15:55:05 [INFO] access_time:1369810505, item_id:1, start, 
    2013-05-29T15:55:05 [INFO] access_time:1369810505, item_id:2, start, 
    ....
```

What I want to do is to make a file that groups the last 7 files. For example, if today we are 20130611, by running the script, I should be able to have a temp file were the content from log20130611 log20130610 log 20130609 log20130608 log20130607 log20130606 and log201305 are inside. So if every file, say, had 4 lines, the new temp file should have 28 lines.

So far what I know is how to read the last 7 files with "glob":

```
    my @file_locations = reverse sort glob("/home/adrian/app/var/log/log*");                                                                               
    if ( @file_locations > 7 ) { $#file_locations = 6; }
```

But I do not know how to group them into a single file. Any ideas?

Comment: why not just use cat and > for the first one and cat >> for the subsequent ones?

Comment: better simply copy selected files in a folder and than tar them, you anyways don't want to read them daily.

Comment: I would first get a `glob` of the files you want and then once you know they're the correct files, loop over them and write them in append mode to another combined file.

Comment: yes this script is supposed to run weekly as daemon with cron, so i cant copu the files manually. And the glob part is ok but the "write them in append mode to another combined file" not really, how do i do that, just printing? mmm them it seems that this script will be too slow T.T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for my $qfn_in (@file_locations) {
    open(my $fh_in, '<', $qfn_in) or die $!;
    print($fh_out $_) while <$fh_in>;
}
```

---

As a one-liner:

```
perl -pe'BEGIN {
   @ARGV = reverse sort @ARGV;
   splice(@ARGV, 7);
}' /home/adrian/app/var/log/log* > combined
```

Comment: thanks a lot! mm I run it (the first version), and got the following: Global symbol "$fh_in" requires explicit package name

Comment: @adriancdperu Did you remember `my`?

Answer (score 0):

If I wasn't already using Perl, if I wasn't wanting to add this to an existing script, then I'd just do something like this:

```
cat $(ls /home/adrian/app/var/log/log*|head -7) > /home/adrian/app/var/log/combined.log
```

Otherwise, ikegami's solution is fine.  If strace reveals that perl is using too many syscalls per too little I/O for you, you can drop down to sysread/syswrite with a buffer size of your choosing.